# "renormalising" a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am looking for the most effective way to solve the following problem:

EDITED (for clarification):

I have a large table `MyTable`, say $200$ columns and $10^5$ rows. For each row, 2 of the columns are relevant for my problem, For instance the two first ones, `MyTable[[All,1]]` and `MyTable[[All,2]]`. These columns contain positive real numbers

Now I want Mathematica to create a 2 dimensional array such that it organizes the elements of `MyTable` by blocks according to the (increasing) values the two first columns, i.e. `MyTable[[All,1]]` and `MyTable[[All,2]]`.

For example, suppose that the values of  `MyTable[[All,1]]` and `MyTable[[All,2]]` both range from $0$ to $10$ (positive real numbers), and I want the "blocks" of `MyList` be sized $1\times1$, meaning by this that `MyList` will be a $10\times10$ array such that:

`MyList[[1,1]]` -> All elements `k` of `MyTable` such that `0<MyTable[[k,1]]<=1 &&  0<MyTable[[k,2]]<=1`

`MyList[[2,1]]` -> All elements of `MyTable` such that `1<MyTable[[k,1]]<=2 &&  0<MyTable[[k,2]]<=1`

`MyList[[3,1]]` -> All elements of `MyTable` such that `2<MyTable[[k,1]]<=3 &&  0<MyTable[[k,2]]<=1`

....

`MyList[[1,1]]` -> All elements of `MyTable` such that `0<MyTable[[k,1]]<=1 &&  0<MyTable[[k,2]]<=1`

`MyList[[1,2]]` -> All elements of `MyTable` such that `0<MyTable[[k,1]]<=1 &&  1<MyTable[[k,2]]<=2`

`MyList[[1,3]]` -> All elements of `MyTable` such that `0<MyTable[[k,1]]<=1 &&  2<MyTable[[k,2]]<=3`

....

How can I do it?

P.S: I have edited the post hoping that it is clearer now.

Comment: Take a look at `GatherBy[ ]`

Comment: Suppose  columns `i` and `j` are the pertinent columns, and I have found a row `k` of `MyTable` for which `m - 1 < x = MyTable[[k, i]] < m` and `n - 1 < y = MyTable[[k, j]] < n`, what exactly would I assign to `MyList[[m, n]]`? "All elements of `MyTable` such that `m - 1 < x < m` &&  `n - 1 < y < n`" is too vague a specification to be coded, so your question can not be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want, especially with the requirement that `i−1<x<i` with `x` integer. There is no integer that will fit between two successive integers, so I shall take it you intended to write `i−1<x<=i`.

Let's define a small test set with x and y the first two columns:

```
t = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {100, 3}];
```

Then:

```
Map[
  MatrixForm, 
    Table[
      Select[t, i - 1 < #[[1]] <= i && j - 1 < #[[2]] <= j &],
      {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}
    ], 
    {2}
] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry, you are right I might have been not 100% clear. By "x" and "y" I meant the values of the 2 relevant columns, say 'x=MyTable[[All,1]]' and  'y=MyTable[[All,2]]', and these values are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I had not been clear. I finally did it using the approach suggested by @Sjoerd C. de Vries. I defined the size of the blocks as the "resolution", and the extrema as the min and max values, instead of $[0,10]$ (something that I did not ask for though ).

```
t = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {100, 3}];

minx = Min@t[[All, 1]];
maxx = Max@t[[All, 1]];
miny = Min@t[[All, 2]];
maxy = Max@t[[All, 2]];
resx = 10;
resy = 10;
stepx = (maxx - minx)/resx;
stepy = (maxy - miny)/resy;
Map[MatrixForm, 
  Table[Select[t, 
    minx + stepx*(i - 1) < #[[1]] <= minx + stepx* i && 
      miny + stepy*(j - 1) < #[[2]] <= miny + stepy*j &], {i, 1, 
    resx}, {j, 1, resy}], {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Output]
Thank you very much for your help!